# Dynamics AX financial stock

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2009

I have a stock dimension set up on several items. I don't want to add dimensions I just want a current stock dimension that is enabled to be recognised during financial update of stock. I thought I could create a new dimension group and add the same dimensions as the previous one except I have checked serial numbers to be part of financial stock update. I just want to know if this is ok?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a new tracking dimension group where the flag "Financial inventory" is active for dimension "Serial number", yes. Since the gui allows you to do that, this is ok from a technical point of view (if you are asking if this makes sense as a business requirement, this would be the wrong place to ask that).

You may run into problems if you want to change the tracking dimension group on an existing product. I think you can only do this as long as the product has not been used in any transactions yet.

Comment: That is my issue, it was suggested for 9 months FIFO is how they do costing at an item a warehouse level. We find out that after first month close that FIFO is no good and they do actually costing on serial numbered items. I guess then it is remove inventory from current items and item groups, then journal them into new codes with new item groups?

Comment: If by "new codes" you mean new items/products then yes, that sounds like a good and clean solution (from a technical point of view), provided the customer is willing to  replace all the existing product numbers with new product numbers (also make sure the business impact is known to all stakeholders).

Comment: Also take a look at [How to change the Storage dimension group on items with existing Inventory transactions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/axsupport/archive/2015/10/01/how-to-change-the-storage-dimension-group-on-items-with-existing-inventory-transactions.aspx), this could be a valid way to  change the tracking dimension group, too. @Joshoohaa